# php grab all GET variables in URL, and send them as POST variables back to same URL

Tags: php

I'd like to clear my URL.

When people hit my website, they usually come to something like this:

www.site.com/webpage/?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3

is it possible to grab all of those GET variables, send them as POST, reload the page, and the grab all the newly sent POST variables to clean the url?

So to a user visiting the page, in the end it would just look like www.site.com/webpage/

Comment: why don't you just rewrite the URL using .htaccess?

Comment: another approach is to set those variables into sessions

Comment: @nomistic That won't change what appears in the browser's location bar.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't setting them as sessions in the previous page instead of sending into the URL prevent this?

Comment: You can only do that if the previous page is a PHP script on your server.

Comment: okay, that is a much more literal reading, but I gather that is what he was  doing

Comment: I thought the links could be coming from another site, bookmarks, google, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the `GET` parameters into a session variable and redirect back to the URL without any parameters. When called without parameters, get the parameters from the session.

```
session_start();
if (empty($_GET) && isset($_SESSION['_GET'])) {
    // This is the page after the redirect, copy the session variable back into $_GET
    $_GET = $_SESSION['_GET'];
} elseif (!empty($_GET)) {
    // When called with parameters, copy $_GET into a session variable
    $_SESSION['_GET'] = $_GET
    // and then redirect to the page with no parameters
    header("Location: /webpage/");
    exit();
}
unset($_SESSION['_GET']); // So it's only used once
// Use $_GET in the rest of the script as normal
```

Comment: So this will automatically get any variables passed in the URL, and send them as post? I don't have to add each unique variable?

Comment: There's no POST. When you redirect, it's another GET request, but the second request doesn't have any URL parameters. That's why I save them all in the session variable, and copy it back into `$_GET` after the redirect.

Comment: Sorry for the noob questions, so how do I get all the variables on the new empty url page?

Comment: They're in `$_GET`. Don't you see the line `$_GET = $_SESSION['_GET'];`?

Comment: do you have paypal? i'd like to send a tip :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make the browser send a post request with any redirect code - which would be needed.

Second thing: Sending POST requests will disable caching and constantly annoy people that use the back button of the browser with the question of "do you want to send that data again".

Best thing would be to avoid putting stuff that you dont like into the URL (aka URL design), but apart from your dislike, this URL works as good or bad as anything else.